# horizontal scroll in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a site for mob using jquery mobile.

I have a content div in my application and I need to scroll / slide horizontally so that I can show all the contents in that div. I am very new to jQuery mob, mobile application. Please help.

My CSS  looks like

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100px;float:left;background-color:olive;overflow:show;" id="container">

<div style="width:550px;height:90px;float:left;background-color:pink;" id="content">
dfg dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg dfg dfg dfg 
</div>
</div>
```

I need to slide content inside container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an accordion menu:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/